# How to create if statement to handle a empty string in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am looking to create a case to say something else if my string is empty, how can I do that?

```
<div class="padding" id="dealBorder">
    <pre id="informationDealText"><pan class="inner-pre" style="font-size: 24px; color: white;" ><font face="times new roman">{{data.$value}}</font></span></pre>

</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question? You can use jQuery/JavaScript to get the value and trigger actions according to your requirements.

Comment: How do you do this in the html?

Comment: in html? html is not a programming or scripting language, its a markup language (Hyper Text **Markup Language**)

Comment: @Doopler I have added an answer. You cannot do it in HTML, you need to use some scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) - very straightforward to use - it evaluates if the statement you pass it is true and renders the element accordingly.

Ex.

```
 <style>
     .inline-styles-are-bad {
       color: 'white';
       font-size: 22px;
     }
     .font-tags-are-worse {
       font-family: 'times new roman', serif; /* bless your users */
     }
 </style>
<pre id="#someID">
 <span class="inline-styles-are-bad font-tags-are-worse" ng-if="data.value.length > 0">{{data.value}}</span>
 <span ng-if="data.value.length == 0">Something else</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: Other users have provided answers in vanilla javascript and Arjun has provided an answer that will not compile. Use ng-if on this one. Alternatively, evaluate your data.value in your controller and substitute the desired text: `if(!data.value || data.value.length == 0) data.value = 'Some text';`

Comment: ng if was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you looking for. I have not executed this code, so please give it a try.

```
<div class="padding" id="dealBorder">
    <pre id="informationDealText"><pan class="inner-pre" style="font-size: 24px; color: white;" ><font face="times new roman">{{data.$value}}</font></span></pre>

</div>
<script>
    if({{data.$value}} = "" || {{data.$value}} = null){
        $('#informationDealText').text("string empty!");
    }
</script>
```